# What Win32 drawing function does SDL2's software renderer use under the hood?

Tags: c, winapi, sdl, sdl-2

There are many GDI functions, such as SetPixel(), but it is very expensive to set each pixel to a certain color, so I wonder what function does the library use.

Searched the SDL2 source code, didn't find the drawing function.

Comment: Build SDL2 in debug mode, then debug the drawing function.

Comment: SDL uses the Direct3D api on Windows.  Which takes care of software rendering by itself.  Also available directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/directx-warp

Comment: SDL's graphics subsystem is just a wrapper around the graphics API of the underlying OS. That means, depending on OS, it can use OpenGL, Vulkan, Metal or Direct3D. On Windows, it uses Direct3D.

Answer (score 1):

> Searched the SDL2 source code, didn't find the drawing function.

You mean [this one](https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/blob/master/src/render/software/SDL_render_sw.c#L558)? As you can see, SDL2's software renderer just works with surfaces like SDL1 did, and a `SDL_RenderCopy` roughly translates to a `SDL_BlitSurface`.

`SDL_BlitSurface` is an alias for `SDL_UpperBlit`, which calls `SDL_LowerBlit`, which calls `src->map->blit`, which can be many things but might be for example [`SDL_BlitCopy`](https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/blob/6ecaa6b61372e5b2f9bd01201814d07e34bb4186/src/video/SDL_blit_copy.c#L91), and that finally does the copying of pixels. Of course pixels aren't set one by one manually. Well, unless you use `SDL_RenderDrawPoints` (that translates to [`SDL_DrawPoints`](https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/blob/6ecaa6b61372e5b2f9bd01201814d07e34bb4186/src/render/software/SDL_drawpoint.c#L65) for a software renderer).